# using mysqli prepared stmt within "if" condition with "||" and "&&" operator

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am just learning mysqli prepared statements and now i have run into a problem and could not get a way out of it. It is the registration form and takes in "username" "email" and "password". if username and email already exists in the database then it doesnot allow registeration. i've used post method and the code is as,

```
//validating email
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
    echo "invalid email";
    exit();
}
//valid email
else{
    //prepared query
    $query_name = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?";
    $query_email = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = ?";

    //prepared statements
    $stmt_name = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query_name);
    $stmt_email = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query_email);

    //if bind failure
    if((!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_name, "s", $user_name)) && (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_email, "s", $user_email))){
         echo "bind unsuccessfull";
         exit();
           }
          else{
             //if execution fails
               if( !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_name) && !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_email)){
                   echo "stmt execution failed";
                   exit();

               }
               //else if execution success
               else{

                    $result_name = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_name);
                    $result_email = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_email);
                    //rows
                    $row_name = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_name);
                    $row_email = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_email);
                    echo $row_name;
                    echo $row_email;
               }
         }

}
```

it looks like the first part before `&&` in `if` condition works and the second doesnot work at all. i have tried registering it with existing "email" in the database but the result is still 0.
the connection is fine and works!
Any help will be appreciated>

Comment: you could make it a single query like `$query_name = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? OR user_email = ?";` and that way you don't even need to check two statement.

Comment: 1) Try to change `&&` to `||`, you require both conditions to fail. It is possible that one of the statements fails and just continues the execution of the script. 2) Do you want to have multiple people with the same first name registered on your website? Because what you are doing now only allows one distinct first name.

Comment: yes i want only one distinct first name and also i would like to know whether we can use two prepared statement in `if` condition or not.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes, thanks i did check your answer it works that way but i want to know wheather  only `user_name` matches or only `user_email` matches or both matches. so i have created two queries instead.

Comment: @Orzoon  it will take care of each condition like username match or emil match or both matched

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks. and in addition to this i would like to know whether we can execute two prepared statement from if conidtion or not . for example `if(mysqli_stmt_execute($query1) and mysqli_stmt_execute($query2))` . will database be able to perform this at the same time or not.

Comment: @Orzoon you can execute two prepared statements but they have to different from each-other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing so much complex code, use single query to do your job

```
//validating email
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
    echo "invalid email";
    exit();
}
else{

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? OR user_email = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user_name, $user_email);

   if( !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
       echo "stmt execution failed";
       exit();

   }else{

        $result_name = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_name);
        $result_email = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_email);
        //rows
        $row_name = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_name);
        $row_email = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_email);
        echo $row_name;
        echo $row_email;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$query_name = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? OR user_email = ?";
you don't need to check the condition twice at same time.If someone will login through email or username then this query will check for both username and email.

Comment: actually it is a registration form so i want to know weather only "username" matches or wheather only "email" matches or both. so i have used two different queries.

Comment: By using my query you can check for both. In this condition you can match both username and email for login.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to roll both queries together using an `or` condition in conjunction with a `try/catch` block so that you can throw exceptions at certain stages if a condition is not met.

```
if( !isset( $user_email ) or !filter_var( $user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) === true ) {

    exit("invalid email");

} else {
    try{
        if( isset( $user_name, $user_email ) ){

            $sql='select `user_name`,`user_email` from `users` where `user_name` = ? or  user_email = ?'
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

            if( $stmt ){

                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_name, $user_email );
                $result=$stmt->execute();

                if( $result ){

                    $stmt->store_result();

                    if( $stmt->num_rows == 1 ){
                        /* user name &/or email already exists */
                        $stmt->bind_result( $name, $email );
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        printf('whoohoo! - found user "%s" with email "%s"', $name, $email );

                    } else {
                        /* no record for username or email*/

                        /* sql query to insert new user */

                    }
                    $stmt->free_result();
                    $stmt->close();

                } else {
                    throw new Exception('sql query failed to return any results');
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('unable to prepare sql');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('username &/or email are missing');
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```